# how to confirm if the weights of my pytorch model has been quantized

Tags: python, pytorch, quantization, intel-lpot

I was able to successfully quantise a pytorch model for huggingface text classification with intel lpot([neural compressor](https://github.com/intel/neural-compressor))

I now have the original fp32 model and quantised int8 models in my machine. For inference I loaded the quantised lpot model with the below code

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('fp32/model/path')
from lpot.utils.pytorch import load  
modellpot = load("path/to/lpotmodel/", model)
```

I am able to see time time improvement of sorts, But I wanted to confirm if the model weights have been actually quantized and use data types such as int8,fp16 etc, which should be ideally the reason of speed up. I iterate over the model weights and print dtypes of the weights, but I see all weights are of type fp32

```
for param in modellpot.parameters():
  print(param.data.dtype)
```

output

```
torch.float32
torch.float32
torch.float32
torch.float32
torch.float32
torch.float32
torch.float32
..
...
```

How do I verify if my pytorch model has been quantised?

Comment: You can check values of weights by: print(list(model.named_parameters()))
Maybe it helps anyhow

Answer (score 0):

Use **print(modellpot)** to check whether the model is quantized. For example, **Linear layer** will be converted to **QuantizedLinear** layer.
Actually, only layers that are supported in PyTorch will be converted into Quantized layer, so not all parameters are int8/uint8.

When the model is printed in the output for each you would be able to see the datatype eg the model output would show dtype as  **qint8** if int8 quantisation has been performed while printing the model.